# Insufficient privileges executing Azure function cmdlet Get-AzADAppCredential

Tags: azure, azure-powershell

Im working on an Azure function that tries to get and update a client secret for an Azure app registration. Function runs as a **managed identity**, and tries to execute Azure powershell cmdlet `New-AzADAppCredential`, `Remove-AzADAppCredential`, and `Get-AzADAppCredential`.

But, upon the execution Im getting an error `Insufficient privileges to complete the operation`.

I tried assigning my function a Contributor role, under Azure role assignments, and I also tried giving a delegated permissions `Directory.ReadWrite.All` for an app registration that the function is trying to access. However, Im still seeing the same error.

I would like to know what permissions are necessary for a managed identity azure function to be able to manage an app registration client secrets.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [RBAC roles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/overview) are used to manage resources in azure subscriptions, in this case, what you need is the permission in Azure AD, not in the subscription.

To fix the issue, the easiest way is to give the [`Application Administrator`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/roles/permissions-reference#application-administrator) to your managed identity.

Navigate to the azure portal -> `Azure Active Directory` -> `Roles and administrators` -> `Application Administrator` -> add the managed identity to the role like below.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I assigned an Application Administrator role to my function, and it worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The `Contributor` role allows the assignee to manage and access the resource, but as you have discovered that does not include managing access. Similarly, `Directory.ReadWrite.All` is for user data not RBAC. There are [two roles for RBAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/built-in-roles)- `Owner` and `User Access Administrator`. Owner is Contributor and UA Admin only allows access control.